# Run Windows command through Java Tomcat Server

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, cmd, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG library files on my windows machine to convert media files from one format to another, so i try to call FFMPEG windows command through java. It works by calling `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -i " + xxx.mp4 + " " + yyy.wav + "");` in normal java program. but when i launch my project into TOMCAT server it throws exception like `java.io.IOException: cannot run program : "ffmpeg" CreateProcess error=2, the system cannot find the file specified` . I have attached my code below..

```
String sVideo = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\voice.amr";
    String dVideo2 = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\sVideo.wav";
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -i " + sVideo + " " + dVideo2 + "");          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

above code works, when runs this class file separately but when i use this code in my project, it throws exception when run my project in TOMCAT Server. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your current dir is somewhere in your tomcat (webapp), did you try to use the full ffmpeg.exe path instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ProcessBuilder` to create the process with path folder to run the program.

```
String folder = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop";
String[] cmdarray = new Sring[]{"ffmpeg -i","voice.amr", "sVideo.wav"};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( cmdarray );
processBuilder.directory(new File(folder));
Process process = processBuilder.start();

int exitCode = -1;
boolean finished = false;
while ( !finished ) {
    exitCode = process.waitFor();
    finished = true;
}
```

The `cmdarray` will have your executable and the parameters if it's needed.